# php database check id

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if an ID exist in the database so I can delete it, and if not display a message warning. PROBLEM when comparing "x" with "xtrue".

```
$x = $_REQUEST['X'];
$y = $_REQUEST['Y'];
if($x != "") {
    $xtrue = " SELECT x
                FROM ".$y."
                WHERE x=".$x;

    if($x == $xtrue) {
        $query="DELETE FROM ".$y." WHERE id=".$x;

        $recordset = mysql_query($query,$conn);

        echo "-> ".$x." from ".$y." deleted.";
        }
    else{echo "There is no ".$x." from ".$y.".";}
}
```

Comment: There are many things wrong here: use of deprecated `mysql_*()`; no escaping of input variables; no testing of existence of input variables; failure to execute query; failure to test result of query for error; race condition with two queries. There might be more. What's your question?

Comment: How could x possibly equal xtrue, ever? When xtrue is a string that contains x plus a bunch of other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not use `mysql_*` (since PHP5.5.0 it's deprecated) but if you must below is example of how to do this.

You don't need to check if record exists, just try to delete it and use `mysql_affected_rows` to determine if any record was deleted.

```php
$x = $_REQUEST['x'];
$y = $_REQUEST['y'];

// Basic validation
// $x must be integer and $y may contains only letters and underscore
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $x) and preg_match('/^[_a-z]+$/', $y)) {

    // If record is not exists it will not be removed
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM $y WHERE id = $x");

    if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
        echo 'Record was deleted';
    } else {
        echo 'Record not exists.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$x = $_REQUEST['X'];
$y = $_REQUEST['Y'];
/*Validation*/
if($x!="" && preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $x) && preg_match('/^[_a-z]+$/', $y)){
 $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT x FROM ? WHERE x=?");
 $sql->execute(array($y,$x));
 if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
  $query=$dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM ? WHERE id=?");
  $query->execute(array($y,$x));
  echo "-> ".$x." from ".$y." deleted.";
 }else{
  echo "There is no ".$x." from ".$y.".";
}
```

More About PDO : [php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: There are many things wrong here: use of deprecated mysql_*(); no escaping of input variables; no testing of existence of input variables; failure to test result of query for error; race condition with two queries. There might be more.